# How to get the probabilities for each class for multi-label classification in Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I'm training a network on a multi-label dataset.

My training file looks like this:

```
img1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 .... 1
...
...
imgN 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 .... 0
```

From reading the tutorials I understand that I have to use the SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss layer.

My question is, after training, what layer do I need to use to extract with the extract_feat.bin script the probabilities for each label?

Bellow I wrote the last layer of my network.

Thank you!

```
layer {
  name: "fc8-1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8-1"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 12400
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
     }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
  bottom: "fc8-1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: why fc8-1 has num_output: 12400 if you only have 8 binary labels????

Comment: Hi @Shai, It is just an example how I have my training file. The real one has 12400 labels/image. I will edit my post to avoid confusion. Thank you!

Comment: @Shai, What I want to achieve is to extract the probabilities and then put a threshold or something to get the relevant labels for the test images. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When training with `"SigmoidCrossEntropy"` loss layer, you need to *replace* the loss layer with a simple `"Sigmoid"` layer for test time:

```
layer {
  type: "Sigmoid"
  bottom: "fc8-1"
  top: "class_prob"
  name: "class_prob"
}
```

Your test-time output should be 12,400 dimensional vector (per input) all entries in range `[0..1]` representing class probabilities.

Comment: What's the interpretation whenever all values are near to 0.50? (between 0.46 and 0.59).

I'm not sure if I'm doing it well, but the last training I did, loss started at 2, then went down til getting around 0.28. I think that is a good learning, but I can't understand